# Bing web search api advanced query

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, bing-api, web-search

I have a question about bing web search api :

I want use a filter in my query for :

- articles + documents
- articles only
- documents only

Articles are html pages
Documents are pdf, doc, docx, ... with /lfy/documents/ path

I have tried with ext parameter but he seems not work with ext:html

I try filtering by path (contains "/documents" for documents, don't contains  /documents for web pages)

1/ Filter including site with syntax error

> q=site:www.msa.fr/lfy/ Barèmes des cotisations sur sallaires

-> return results :-)

Altered query is : "alteredQuery": "barèmes des cotisations sur salaires"

sallaires become salaires : ok !

2/ Filter including site and excluding sub site  with syntax error

> q=site:www.msa.fr/lfy/ NOT site:www.msa.fr/lfy/documents Barèmes des cotisations sur sallaires

-> return no results

Adding NOT site: break the syntax correction

3/ Filter including site and excluding sub site  without syntax error

> q=site:www.msa.fr/lfy/ NOT site:www.msa.fr/lfy/documents Barèmes des cotisations sur salaires

-> return results

Adding "NOT site:xxx" break the syntax correction

Note : i use

- responseFilter=Webpages
- mkt=fr-fr
- safesearch=Moderate

Every one have a solution ?

Thanks for your help.

Florian.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "-" instead of "NOT". The below should work:

```
q=Barèmes des cotisations sur sallaires site:www.msa.fr/lfy/

q=Barèmes des cotisations sur sallaires site:www.msa.fr/lfy/ -site:www.msa.fr/lfy/documents
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.

But with 

q=Barèmes des cotisations sur sallaires site:www.msa.fr/lfy/ -site:www.msa.fr/lfy/documents

It's same result : the syntax correction don't work ... How can i have an altered query with "Barèmes des cotisations sur salaires" (sallaires -> salaires)